# TableAlias__ColumnAlias syntax in virtual fields not being parsed as documented

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.9

[Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) state that we can name calculated fields using a syntax like `Timelog__TotalHours` and PHP will parse it as:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [ProductsItems] => Array
        (
            [Total] => 50
    )
)
```

In my CakePHP/2.9.4 set up I'm trying it in several places, such as [pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#pagination-and-virtual-fields-set-in-controller-with-joins), but I get the column name handled as any other string:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [ProductsItems__Total] => 50
)
```

My test code in the controller is:

```
$this->Paginator = $this->Components->load(
    'Paginator',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            "CONCAT_WS(' ', Usuario.nombre, Usuario.apellidos) AS Usuario__Empleado",
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Usuario',
        ),
        'limit' => 2,
    )
);
debug($this->Paginator->paginate());
```

... and prints:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Usuario__Empleado' => 'Juan García'
        ),
        'Usuario' => array(
            'id' => '56'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Usuario__Empleado' => 'María López'
        ),
        'Usuario' => array(
            'id' => '385'
        )
    )
)
```

Do I need explicitly to enable this feature somewhere?

Comment: will you please share your query code

Comment: @tarikul05 Sure, here it is.

Comment: Do you actually define the virtual field on the model somewhere?

Comment: @ndm No, I don't (I assumed it was unnecessary if you specify the column within the query). But doing so doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should define the virtual field before your query (can be model or controller).

```
$this->CurrentModel->Usuario->virtualFields['Empleado'] = 0;
$this->Paginator = $this->Components->load(
    'Paginator',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            "CONCAT_WS(' ', Usuario.nombre, Usuario.apellidos) AS Usuario__Empleado",
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Usuario',
        ),
        'limit' => 2,
    )
);
debug($this->Paginator->paginate());
```

It should work.

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. I admit I don't fully understand the mechanism, though. If the field needs to be already defined, what's the point of the ad-hoc definition? It's just a way to override the original definition?